# Storage policies

Tags: c++, strings, template-meta-programming

I often come across situations where a library component needs to buffer a large amount of data for later processing. The problem is that at the design stage a choice needs to be made as to whether to store copies of, or references to, the data. Both methods have advantages/disadvantages:

- Storing copies requires either duplicating the data, or temporarily giving up ownership.
- Storing references creates a dependency on the lifetime of the callers data.

It would be nice if the component could offer a choice of either method.

I've had a go at implementing a policy-based solution to this problem. This solution only works for `std::string` types, but could easily be extended to other types.

The 'policies' look like this:

```
class StoreStringCopy
{
protected:
    using InputType     = const std::string&;
    using ValueType     = std::string;
    using ReferenceType = boost::string_ref;

    StoreStringCopy() = default;

    ReferenceType store(InputType value)
    {
        auto copy_it = copies_.emplace(value);
        return *copy_it.first;
    }

private:
    std::unordered_set<ValueType> copies_;
};

class StoreStringReference
{
protected:
    using InputType     = boost::string_ref;
    using ValueType     = boost::string_ref;
    using ReferenceType = boost::string_ref;

    StoreStringReference() = default;

    ReferenceType store(InputType value)
    {
        return value;
    }
};
```

And here is a simple use-case which stores sub-strings of the data:

```
template <typename StoragePolicy>
class Foo : StoragePolicy
{
public:
    using typename StoragePolicy::InputType;

    Foo() = default;
    void add(InputType s)
    {
        ReferenceType c = store(s);
        substrings_.emplace_back(c.substr(0, c.length() - 1));
        substrings_.emplace_back(c.substr(1, c.length() - 1));
    }

    void print() const
    {
        for (const auto& ss : substrings_) {
            std::cout << ss << std::endl;
        }
    }

private:
    using typename StoragePolicy::ReferenceType;
    using StoragePolicy::store;

    std::vector<ReferenceType> substrings_;
};
```

The advantage of this design is that the user can easily switch strategy at compile-time depending on the context.

I am looking for critiques of this design, and any improvements.